# How do I create classes and objects in PHP

Tags: php, class, object

How do I create classes and objects, and how do I call them?

Answer (score 8):

Why show you when you can review the manual?

[PHP: Classes and Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)

Comment: It's better off to read the documentation anyways, plus it gives the op an insight where to reference any other topics in the future.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
class Widget {

}

$widget = new Widget();
?>
```

Comment: But seriously, what he said ^

Answer (score 1):

see this

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

http://evolt.org/node/48911/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a class which objects are callable (in PHP 5.3), than you need to defined __invoke magic method  in your class, e.g.

```
<?php 

class MyClass {

     public function __invoke($x)  {
        var_dump($x);
    }
}

$myObject = new MyClass();
$myObject(2);

// output: init(2)

?>
```